# Write out spark df as single parquet file in databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, parquet

I have a dataframe something like below:

| Filename | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| file1 | 1 | 1 |
| file1 | 1 | 1 |
| file2 | 2 | 2 |
| file2 | 2 | 2 |

I need to save this as parquet partitioned by file name. When I use `df.write.partitionBy("Filename").mode("overwrite").parquet(file_out_location)`
it creates 2 folders (based on the partitions) as `Filename=file1` and `Filename=file1` and many part files inside.

How can I save it as a single file within each partition directory, e.g. Filename=file1.parquet and Filename=file2.parquet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```
row = df.selectExpr("cast(count(DISTINCT(FileName)) as int) as cnt").head();

df \
  .repartition(row["cnt"], F.col("FileName"))\
  .write()\
  .partitionBy("FileName")\
  .parquet("output-folder-path/");
```

Essentially you need to partition the in-memory dataframe based on the same column(s) which you intent on using in `partitionBy()`. Without giving `row["cnt"]` as above - it'll default to `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` partitions.

The above will produce one file per partition based on the partition column.

Without repartition:
[image: Output1]

With repartition:
[image: Output]

Comment: But what if i don't want it in a folder, as you write, but actually want to control the output filename, i.e. not a folder, but the fil instead?